# Need help switch labels when button pressed in tkInter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I need it so that when I press the button it will switch between 2 labels, when I have managed to create a second statement now I need to be able to switch between the two. I have no clue what to do to get this to work, please help

```
def changeLabelText():

z = True
print(z)
if z == True:
    print("The current text is", l1['text'])
    z = False
    return z
elif z == False:
    print("The current text is", l12['text'])
    z = True
    return z
l1['text'] = "Changed Text"
l12['text'] = "Text"

b1 = Button(app, text="Change Text", command=changeLabelText)
l1 = Label(app, text="Text")
l12 = Label(app, text="New Text")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear for what reason you're using those redundant conditions, but here's a small example how you can switch labels (technically - a text options as your function's name claims):

```
try:
    import tkinter as tk
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk


def changeLabelText():
    l1['text'], l2['text'] = l2['text'], l1['text']


app = tk.Tk()

b1 = tk.Button(app, text="Change Text", command=changeLabelText)
l1 = tk.Label(app, text="Text")
l2 = tk.Label(app, text="New Text")

l1.pack()
l2.pack()
b1.pack()

app.mainloop()
```